# IOT_LAUNCHER activity not starting on boot

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-things

I have a Xamarin app built to run on Android. I am attempting to run it on a Raspberry Pi 3 on Android Things. I have flashed the default image and I can successfully run the app via Visual Studio when connected to the pi.

However, I cannot get the app to start on boot either by installing via adb or by creating a bundle and building via the Android Things console. I have setup the manifest correctly I believe.

My MainActivity has the correct properties:

```
Activity(Label = "PropertyVision", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/PVLightTheme")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryLauncher })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" })]
```

I can install and run the APK via ADB and when pulled back I can analyze the APK and see that the manifest does indeed have the correct intent-filters but when I restart the device I get the standard Android Things dashboard.

```
<activity
    android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0199"
    android:label="PropertyVision"
    android:name="md5cbdbb5fa2925f03038c91923122a6627.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Using 0.6.0-preview. When I create a bundle.zip and create a new build via Android Things console it also boots into the standard dashboard but I can start my app via adb.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your manifest to contain **two** intent filters within the application tag, one for debugging and one for IoT boot.

> Android Things expects one application to expose a "home activity" in its manifest as the main entry point for the system to automatically launch on boot. This activity must contain an intent filter that includes both CATEGORY_DEFAULT and IOT_LAUNCHER.

To do this via `Activity` attributes:

```
[Activity(Label = "KeyPadEntry", Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryLauncher })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER", Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
  ~~~
}
```

The generated manifest should look something like this within the application tag:

```
<activity android:name="md5228f519fe41cfb3cf46c839bf977fe9b.MainActivity"">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>

    ~~~~

</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried your suggestion and checked the resulting APK and the manifest does look correct. I'll give it a try on the device tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for that, been struggling with getting this working for 2 days. Didn't realise I needed to intent-filters!